# Get rid of timestamp in CodeFluent generated source files

Tags: timestamp, code-generation, codefluent

CodeFluent includes a comment with a timestamp in all generated .cs files  :

```
// CodeFluent Entities generated (http://www.softfluent.com). Date: Thursday, 05 September 2013 14:34.
```

The timestamp is regenerated whether the files changed or not. This is a problem because TFS will see this comment as a change in the source files when checking in (which is normal). Then we end up with all generated files included in every changeset after each code generation.

Is there a way to get rid of that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeFluent Entities provides an option to remove the "generation date and time" when running producers.
The option may be defined at the producer level or at the project level (applied to all of your producers)

- At producer level

Select the producer and set the productionFlags property to "RemoveDates"

```
<cf:producer productionFlags="Overwrite, RemoveDates">
</cf:producer>
```

- At project level

Select the project and set the defaultProducerProductionFlag property (in the advanced tab) to "RemoveDates"

```
<cf:project defaultProducerProductionFlags="Overwrite, RemoveDates">
```

The procedure is explained on The Codefluent Entities blog: http://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/04/22/remove-the-current-date-and-time-to-generated-files/

Comment: Those options made CF stop regenarating files but `Overwrite, RemoveDates` instead of `Default, RemoveDates` did the trick.